# how to access result property of Success function of jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a `success` function of jQuery defined as:

```
success: function(result) {
    var htmlString = [result];
    for (i = 0; i < htmlString.length; i++) {
        $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="#">' + htmlString[i].name+ '</a></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    }
},
```

And an event handler bound with `delegate`:

```
$('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {
    var name= ;$(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(0).find('a').text();
    var number = ; //here i need to access htmlString[i].number
    alert(number);
}
```

How can I assign `htmlString[i].number` to the `number` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there may be better ways but one way is to on the `success` callback assign the `result` to some global scope variable and access it in the delegate call

else you can do it this way assign the `htmlString[i].number` to the `rel` tag

```
success: function(result) {

                var htmlString = [result];
                for (i = 0; i < htmlString.length; i++) {

                $('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a rel="'+htmlString[i].number+'" href="#">' + htmlString[i].name+ '</a></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
                }

            },
```

and in the delegate call

```
     $('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {

                var name= $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(0).find('a').text();
                var number =  $('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {

                var name= $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(0).find('a').text();
                var number = $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(0).find('a').attr('rel');
                alert(number);
    }
            alert(number);
}
```

Comment: var number = $(this).closest('tr').find("td").eq(0).find('a').attr('rel');
              this line wrkd fine for my code thnx 3nigma.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect use case for [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
/*snip */
for (i = 0; i < htmlString.length; i++) {
    var $row = $('<tr><td><a href="#">' + htmlString[i].name + '</a></td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
    $row.find("a.remove").data("number", htmlString[i].number);

    $('#MyGrid tbody').append($row);
}
```

Then in your event handler:

```
$('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {  
    var number = $(this).data("number");
    alert(number);
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/BRZD7/